# Is there an R package that will handle POSIX objects and return the nth N-day of the week?

Tags: r, time, posixct, weekday

I have written a function which, when provided a range of dates, the name of a particular day of the week and the occurrence of that day in a given month (for instance, the second Friday of each month) will return the corresponding date. However, it isn't very fast and I'm not 100% convinced of its robustness. Is there a package or set of functions in R which can do these kinds of operations on POSIX objects? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using the function `nextfri` whose one line source is shown in the [zoo Quick Reference vignette](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/zoo/vignettes/zoo-quickref.pdf) in the [zoo package](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/zoo/index.html) the following gives the second Friday of `d` where `d` is the `"Date"` of the first of the month:

```
library(zoo)
d <- as.Date(c("2011-09-01", "2011-10-01"))
nextfri(d) + 7
## [1] "2011-09-09" "2011-10-14"
```

(`nextfri` is not part of the zoo package -- you need to enter it yourself -- but its only one line)

The following gives the day of the week where 0 is Sunday, 1 is Monday, etc.

```
as.POSIXlt(d)$wday
## [1] 4 6
```

If you really are dealing exclusively with dates rather than date-times then you ought to be using `"Date"` class rather than `"POSIXt"` classes in order to avoid time zone errors.  See the article in [R News 4/1](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/Rnews/Rnews_2004-1.pdf).

Answer (score 0):

The `timeDate` package has some of that functionality; I based this little snippet of code on some code that package.  This is for `Date`s, timeDate has underlying POSIX types.

```
nthNdayInMonth <- function(date,nday = 1, nth = 1){
  wday <- (as.integer(date) - 3) %% 7
  r <- (as.integer(date) + (nth -1) * 7 + (nday - wday)%%7)
  as.Date(r,"1970-01-01")
}
```