# How to retrieve the weekday's date in R?

Tags: r

Is there one function returning the weekday's date? For example, today is 3/25/2015. If input the parameter is current week(0) and weekday is Monday(1), it will return '3/23/2015'. If input is last week(-1) and weekday is Monday(1), it will return '3/16/2015'.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7558619/is-there-an-r-package-that-will-handle-posix-objects-and-return-the-nth-n-day-of/7558895#7558895

Answer (score 0):

I believe as.posix allows you to request $wday

Comment: `as.posix` is not a valid R function.  I think you meant `as.POSIXlt`